# Can anyone help identify this valve?

Tags: valves

Can anyone help identify this type of valve? (see picture below). I've recently bought this bike and am having trouble inflating the front tyre correctly.

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Cheers

[image]

Answer (score 5):

This is a screw-on valve extension for a standard Sclaverand (aka Presta) valve. They are usually fitted when short valves are used with high rims. But here the 3 or so threads visible next to the rim indicate that it may not even be required. Screw it off and you'll find the normal valve-head underneath. If you have a track pump with a screw-on chuck it may fit nicely, with a lever action chuck it could be fiddly.

Comment: It's a Presta extension on a Presta tube. Probably there is not enough valve sticking out of the deep section rim to get a pump on so an extension is needed.

Comment: @ArgentiApparatus aren't you saying the same thing? Sclaverand valve is another name for Presta valve

Comment: This is literally my first time ever hearing of a Sclaverand valve. Double checking on Google, I agree it's a valid name, but I feel your answer would be more broadly useful if you changed it to read "Presta (aka Sclaverand)" since I think more ppl know this valve by the former name than by the latter. Otherwise, great answer and good recommendation on taking the extension off.

Comment: @Swifty I think I started a comment then made it an answer, but forgot to delete the comment

Comment: @SSilk In the European part of the world they are commonly called Sclaverand.

Answer (score 2):

It's a Presta extension on a Presta vavled tube. Probably there is not enough valve sticking out of the deep section rim to get a pump on so an extension is needed.

The head of the extension is not exactly Presta though. I guess that the little knurled barrel sticking out actually goes the length of the extension and connects to the valve stem on the on the underlying valve, so you need to undo it to open the valve to inflate the tube.

What I would do is replace the tubes with ones with a shorter valve, then extend those with better extensions, so that the extension passes through the rim hole and is held steadier.

Comment: Why not just a longer valve? They exist.

Comment: @Carel they do exist, but whoever fitted it may not have had one available, or was using up old tubes from an earlier shallow wheel, or took a tube from a fellow rider, or was using short valve stems for added-aero and forgot to remove the valve extension.